# Android Spinner how to update the selected position (getSelectedItemPosition())?

Tags: java, android, spinner

So I have a Spinner and a EditText to login. The array of the Spinner owns "Anonymous" and " Owner" (means "Anonymous" is 0 and "Owner" is 1 in the array). When you choose "Anonymous" the password is "0000" and when you choose "Owner" the password is "1234".

But when I choose "Owner", the password "1234" is wrong and the Logcat shows "Anonymous". How can I make "Owner" selected? Maybe getSelectedItemPosition() is wrong?

My Code:

```
public class PinEnterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button nextButton;
    EditText pinEditText;
    Spinner pinRoleSpinner = null;
    private String TAG = "PinEnterActivity";
    private Byte selectedUserRole = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pin_enter);

    nextButton = findViewById(R.id.nextActivity)
    pinEditText = findViewById(R.id.pinET);
    pinRoleSpinner = findViewById(R.id.roleSpinner);

    selectedUserRole = (byte) pinRoleSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();

        switch (selectedUserRole) {
        case 0:
            Log.i(TAG, "Anonymous");
            SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("My_Prefs", 0);
            final String password = sharedpreferences.getString("pass", "");
            nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (pinEditText.getText().toString().equals("0000")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(PinEnterActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        pinEditText.setError("Password incorrect");
                        Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(PinEnterActivity.this, R.anim.shake);
                        pinEditText.startAnimation(shake);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            });
            break;

        case 1:
            Log.i(TAG, "Owner");

            SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("My_Prefs", 0);
            final String password2 = preferences.getString("pass", "");

            nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (pinEditText.getText().toString().equals("1234")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(PinEnterActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }else{
                        pinEditText.setError("Password incorrect");
                        Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(PinEnterActivity.this, R.anim.shake);
                        pinEditText.startAnimation(shake);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you cast `getSelectedItemPosition` to byte?

Comment: @ZUNJAE I have to because I declared selectedUserRole as Byte

Comment: But why have you declared it as byte? `getSelectedItemPosition()` returns an int and you should respect the return type.

Comment: @ZUNJAE honestly idk, but I think both works doesn't it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you explain more precisely, where is the first line of code where a value is not what you expected it to be? What is the value and why did you expect it to be something different? More Log statements (`Log.d`) may help.

Comment: @LarsH Thank you! Everything works perfectly until "case 1:" . When the user selects "Owner", the password should be "1234" but it isn't and the Logcat should show "Owner" because of the Log.i. But the password is still "0000" and the Logcat does not display "Owner". Seems like the app doesn't see when "Owner" is chosen.

Comment: You write 'Everything works perfectly until "case 1:"'. Does this mean you logged the value of `selectedUserRole = (byte) pinRoleSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();` and it came out as 1? (Because it sounds like it's not 1, given that you don't see "Owner" in the logcat.)

Comment: Also you write about 'when the user selects "Owner"'. But the user selecting anything happens after `onCreate()` is finished, and yet your switch statement is in `onCreate()`. So how could it reflect the result of a user's choice? Maybe what you meant is to put the switch statement in the listener method for the Next button.

Comment: @LarsH No it does not come out as 1. It's right, selectedUserRole is not 1 because Logcat says only "Anonymous".

Comment: @LarsH ah ok, so as long the switch statement is in `onCreate()` (or as long the nextButton is pressed), my app doesn't see what the user chose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out the right answer.

```
   pinRoleSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            switch(selectedUserRole) {

               case 0:
                      Log.i(TAG, "Anonymous");
                      // Code
                   break;

               case 1:
                      Log.i(TAG, "Owner");
                      // Code
                   break;

               default;
                     // Code
                   break;

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```